# What are the best practices for peer to peer networking in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, p2p

I am planning to create an audio chat application with flutter(using streams from p2p network). By far, I have not found better solution than calling platform specific code for IOS and Android separately. Is there some other better way of doing this ?

I wish there was something in dart that's close to [peerjs](https://peerjs.com/) in JavaScript.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc is what I was looking for.